# How to get one query plan for parameterized nchar?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have c# web application that submits a query to sql server. The query has three parameters, two are ints and one is nchar. I'm getting a different query plan for each length of the nchar parameter. Is there a way to only get one plan?

Some more details:

The query is fairly large and complex, so I won't inlcude it all here. However, there WHERE part is

```
WHERE gp.Control=@Control AND r.RegionType=@RegionType
```

r.RegionType is a column in a table defined as nchar(10). My c# code, sets the parameter with the following:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(parmRegionType, System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar).Value = rgn.Key;
```

where rgn.key may have one of the following four values: "All", "County", "DGP", or "State".

When I dump the query plan with

```
SELECT usecounts, cacheobjtype, objtype, text, query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) 
WHERE text LIKE '%(@RegionType nchar(%),@CacheCnt int,@Control int)%'
AND text NOT LIKE '%this query%'
```

I get the following results (edited format and truncated text)

```
usecounts cacheobjtype  objtype  text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             query_plan
--------- ------------- -------- -----------------------------------------------
1         Compiled Plan Prepared (@RegionType nchar(5),@CacheCnt int,@Control...
1         Compiled Plan Prepared (@RegionType nchar(6),@CacheCnt int,@Control...
2         Compiled Plan Prepared (@RegionType nchar(3),@CacheCnt int,@Control...

(3 row(s) affected)
```

So you can see that there is a query plan for when @RegionType is three characters long ("All" and "DGP"), five characters long ("State") and six characters long ("County").

Is there a way to code this so that only one query plan is prepared independent of the length of the @RegionType parameter?

Comment: Okay I'll ask, seeing as its a varying length parameter why are you passing as a fixed length one of varying sizes?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, I did that because the RegionType is declared as nchar(10) in the database. Seeing the answer from Martin Smith, below, I suppose I shouldn't have.

Comment: It is? Me I'd have avoided that, or made all the content the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NVarChar` and [set the length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x.aspx) to the maximum expected possible value (e.g. whatever the max length of the `RegionType` column is).

Looks like `6` in your case as that is the length of `County`

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(parmRegionType, System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 6).Value = rgn.Key;
```

Comment: Ok, I completely missed the size parameter to Add(). So even though RegionType is defined as nchar(10) in the databse, I should use NVarChar here instead?

Comment: @Russ - I'd normally define the parameters to be the same datatype as the column so `NChar(10)` would be fine. One gotcha with `NCHAR` would occur if your query was doing `r.RegionType LIKE @RegionType + '%'`. That wouldn't work as you would probably hope as the parameters would be padded out with trailing spaces. BTW: Why are you using `NCHAR(10)` as this column definition? The column values are neither fixed length or unicode.

Comment: you bring up two good points. varchar(10) probably would have been better but now it is what it is. Thank you for your help.